# Program to determine whether a Scheduled Task is running or not in .bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 scheduled task say ABC and PQR,i want that if the scheduled task ABC is running then i want to stop it and run the scheduled Task PQR.
if ABC is stopped then just run the PQR.

Comment: This sounds more like an idea than a question.

Answer (score 1):

to check if a task is running:

```
schtasks /query /TN ABC
if %errorlevel%==0 echo ABC is running
```

to delete the scheduled task use

```
schtasks /delete /TN ABC
```

(maybe, you need an additional `/F` (Force))

to create a scheduled task you need some parameters. See `schtasks /create /?`.

If you have any more problems, please come back with the needed parameters and your "best try code"